# Is it normal to have thousands of files in the node_modules/.cache/babel-loader folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm developing a react app, and I noticed over `11,000` JSON files in the `client/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` folder.

Is that to be expected, or is there a way to clear some of the old files?

Comment: Yup, babel caches the compiled files. If you look at your package-lock.json, you probably have a bunch of dependencies. If you want to clear it out, just delete .cache/babel-loader, it'll generate the cache again when you rebuild (albeit possibly a bit slower since you cleared its cache).

Comment: Thanks @cbr! Definitely have a fair amount of dependencies. Will it most likely rebuild close to the same amount of files? Trying to see if there's really any benefit to deleting. I was doing a backup of my directory structure and it was slow because of all of these files.

Comment: You can remove node_modules whenever you're not developing your app. Package.json and package-lock.json ensure that when you run npm install, the same dependencies are downloaded to node_modules. Then, when you start your dev server or build, babel builds the files and caches them. The only benefit to deleting is reclaiming disk space, and usually you would completely exclude node_modules from version control and backups.

Comment: Try renaming node_modules, then npm install and start the dev server. This will simulate deleting node_modules if you're concerned about its effects. Everything will be regenerated.